# How to bind 2 models to one input field in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

Is there anyway that I can bind two model values to one input field?

Suppose I have input field which I want to be the value of two variables in the scope something like:

```
<input type="text" model="sn_number; id" >
```

Comment: The answer is no. But more info would be useful so we could help with suggestions.

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You cannot, but there are some workarounds.

#### 1. Use ngChange to update the other model

```
<input type="text" 
       ng-model="sn_number" 
       ng-change="id=sn_number"/>
```

#### 2. You could watch a model, and when in changes, update another

```
$scope.$watch('sn_number', function(v){
  $scope.id = v;
});
```

You would need to watch also for changes in `id` if you want to keep them in sync.

[Example here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rDvTSdK9V5ozzgxdjNhX?p=preview)

Comment: FYI: the reason this works is because `ng-model` has prio 1 while `ng-change` has prio 0 (as of Angular 1.5)  and therefore is called first

Answer (score 11):

You can bind fields immediately, not only in ng-change, and actually it isn't data binding, its only angular expression

```html
  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name" value="{{name}}"/>

  <label>Key</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="key" value="{{key=name}}" />
```

Comment: It actually worked for me, but can you explain why is it working? why just using 
value ="{{name}}" won't work?

Comment: save my day from writing lots of $watch :)

Answer (score 7):

It would make no sense to bind an input to two variables in the model. Binding works both ways, so if the model is updated, the field is updated and vice-versa. If you were to bind to two variables, what would be the single source of truth?

However you can use ng-change to call a method on the controller which can set two variables when the field changes.

Answer (score 0):

with ng-init

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl" ng-init="model = { year: '2013', month:'09'}">
```

or

```
<div ng-repeat="c in contact" ng-init="likes = { food: 'steak', drink:'coke'}">
```

Comment: "The only appropriate use of ngInit is for aliasing special properties of ngRepeat" 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit