# Clever way to bypass debounce for view?

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

http://jsfiddle.net/2en6hgzb/

Basically, I want my scope.$watch to honor the debounce but would like a separate watcher for my view without debounce. Any non-dirty techniques I can employ?

```
<my-slider></my-slider>

<script type="text/coffeescript">
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive 'mySlider', ->
  link = (scope) ->
    scope.sliderValue = 0
    scope.$watch 'sliderValue', (value) ->
      console.log 'Slider Value: ' + value

  link: link,
  restrict: 'E',
  template:
    'Value: {{sliderValue}}<br>' +
    '<input type="range" step="1" min="0" max="10" ' +
    'ng-model="sliderValue" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 1000 }" />'

angular.bootstrap document, ['myApp']
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: "a separate watcher for my view without debounce"? In your code you are using `ng-model-options` that sets a `debounce` of 1 second to your model. And now you would like to have a `$watch`er for that model without `debounce`? Do you realize how contradictory that sounds? Maybe you could use an intermediate `model` for that, which would defeat the purpose of the `debounce` in the first place. Something like: remove the `ng-model-options` from your `<input type="range"`, set a `$watch`er for that model that implements a `debounce` towards another model. By why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Joseph To psychologically appease the user. Nobody likes to toggle a form control and get delayed feedback, but the back-end processing doesn't need to execute each tick of the slider. How is that contradictory?

Comment: "the back-end processing doesn't need to execute each tick of the slider" <--- The `debounce` option has nothing to do with the back-end. If you set a `debounce` of 1 sec, the model won't be updated until 1 second has passed from the time that the user updated the `input`. In other words: if you have your model set with a `debounce` of 1 sec, you can't get notified of the new value of the model until one second later, because the value of the model won't be updated until one second later. For what you are saying it seems to me that you want is a custom `debounce` function.

Comment: @Josep, this seems to be a pretty common use case. Let's assume I have a textarea that updates the model in the database once every 1s. Now I want to create a custom validator that changes the textarea style for each key that is typed in real time. With debounce I can't do that, unless I somehow deactivate the debounce for one specific watcher.

Comment: By the way, this answer may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13890580

Comment: @FagnerBrack have you had a look at the accepted answer? I'm afraid that your comments have nothing to do with the original problem of the OP.

Comment: Yes I looked the accepted answer. My comment is refering to this: `In your code you are using ng-model-options that sets a debounce of 1 second to your model. And now you would like to have a $watcher for that model without debounce? Do you realize how contradictory that sounds?`. This doesn't seems that contraditory in addition to the similar use-case that I stated above. I assume you were saying in the first comment that this use case doesn't makes sense, but it does and one could assume that Angular may have provided something native to handle this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you want is something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp", []).directive "mySlider", ($timeout) ->
  link = undefined
  link = (scope) ->
    debouncePromise = undefined
    scope.sliderValue = 0
    scope.$watch "sliderValue", (value, oldVal) ->
      return  unless oldVal
      $timeout.cancel debouncePromise  if debouncePromise
      debouncePromise = $timeout(->

        #your call to the server here!
        console.log value
        return
      , 1000)
      return

    return

  link: link
  restrict: "E"
  template: "Value: {{sliderValue}}<br>" + "<input type=\"range\" step=\"1\" min=\"0\" max=\"10\" " + "ng-model=\"sliderValue\" />"
```

## [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/r4vhrz86/1/)