# Using the ng-model

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-model

I am working on a save feature using angularjs, web api and entity frame work.  When the user clicks add new button  I initialize some fields to default values.  I have an itemDetail object and an itemPrice object.  Both have an itemNo field.  On the form itemDetail is updated by the ng-model.  How can I also get that value in the newItemPrice()?

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="itemNo" class="form-control" id="itemNumber" ng-model="vm.item.itemDetail.itemNo" />
```

Controller

```
    function newItemDetail() {
    return {
        id: 0,
        itemId: 0,
        itemNo:'',
        onHandQty: 0,
        storeListPrice: 5000.00,
        inventoried: false,
    }
}

function newItemPrice() {
    return {
        id: 0,
        itemId: 0,
        itemNo: '',
        country: 'USA',
        region: 1,
        discountPercent: 10,
        erpDeleted: false,
        deleteRemote: false,
    }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to alter the object ? OR you wana put the same itemNo value to another input type like this this ng-model="vm.item.itemDetail.itemNo" ?? is this what you are trying to say ?

Comment: yes i'm trying to push the same value in

Comment: In to this ng-model="vm.item.itemDetail.itemNo ?

Comment: yes itemNo is bound to vm.itemitemDetail.itemNo in the newItemDetail()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `ng-change` directive:

```
ng-change="vm.item.itemPrice.itemNo = vm.item.itemDetail.itemNo"
```

Comment: while this is working what is strange is when the data is saved to its saved as 0

Answer (score 0):

Look here:
[How to bind 2 models to one input field in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890331/how-to-bind-2-models-to-one-input-field-in-angular)

Else i would recommend you to change the data structure from 2 objects with IDs into 1 object with 2 propertys.

```
function Item() {
return {
    id: 0,
    itemId: 0,
    itemNo: '',
    price: { 
        onHandQty: 0,
        storeListPrice: 5000.00,
        inventoried: false
    },
    detail:{
        country: 'USA',
        region: 1,
        discountPercent: 10,
        erpDeleted: false,
        deleteRemote: false}
    }
}
```

it seems that you add a comma at the last key/value pairs in your objects I would recommend to remove them i had some wild bughunting them sometimes

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not change the data structure.  It is set that way

Comment: I think there is a way to call a function everytime you change the input. But i am at work and have no time to research that further. //function changeInput(input) {input2 = input; input3=input}