# primeng form, assign from input value to two model parameters

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a primeng form that creates/updates the user model on form submission. I want to update another model at the same time. That is, I want to get the username in the form and create another model object with that value.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="login" #loginInput="ngModel"
                    [(ngModel)]="user.login" required minlength="1" maxlength="50" pattern="^[_.@A-Za-z0-9-]*$">
```

With the `[(ngModel)]="user.login"` I want to save both the `"user.login"` and `modelX.paramX` with the same value. Is it possible to fill both models in the form?

Or do I have to get the value and do it separately in the component.ts? If so how do I do it?

Comment: have you tried `<input ... (change)="someMethod()"` then in the method do the assignment to the modelX.propX. like `modelX.propX = this.user.login`

Comment: Yes, this is how I do it now, I was doing it on submission though. change would make it easier. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way that I have found you can achieve this is by using the change event of the input it will be like this:

```
<input id="twomodel" name="twomodel" [(ngModel)]="X" (change)="Y= X" type="text" #twomodel="ngModel" />
```

see the change event I just made it to assign the bind value to the other value

here is the link that i got this solution from (It uses the angularjs):
[How to bind 2 models to one input field in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13890331/how-to-bind-2-models-to-one-input-field-in-angular)

Hope that helps

Comment: @Tika dont forget this only will assign the value to Y when you focus out of the input